# Attempting to pass variable value to HTA Input box parameter value =

Tags: vbscript, hta

```
--------------------------------
```

In the above a selection is made from the lower input box populated from an array. On selection the corresponding index value from a second array is copied to the clipboard. A message box is used to advise user of value copied to clipbord but this is clunky. I added a second read only input  box to display this value.

```html
<input type="text" id = "Resulta)" / style="text-align:center;" readonly style='width:160px'/ value= bOpt(isel)>
```

The variable `bOpt(isel)` is not recognised as such being treated as text despite being unquoted. is there a simple way around this?

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:Application ID="HTA"
 ApplicationName="ListBox"
form name="myform"
onclick = 'Selected()'
<style type="text/css"> body {overflow-y:hidden;</style>
<style type="text/css"> body {overflow-x:hidden;</style>
Border="thin"
 BorderStyle="normal"
 Caption="no"
:::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px; /* remove scrollbar space /
background: transparent; / optional: just make scrollbar invisible /
scroll = "no"
scrollflat = "no"
Icon=""
 MaximizeButton="yes"
 MinimizeButton="yes"
 ShowInTaskBar="yes"
 SingleInstance="yes"
 SysMenu="no"
 Version="1.0"
 WindowState="maximize"
<script type="text/vbscript">

Option Explicit

Sub Document_OnKeyUp()
  intKeyCode = Window.Event.Keycode
  If intKeyCode = 27 Then Window.Close
End Sub

Dim aOpt, bOpt, iSel, iOpt, sOpt, messij
Sub Window_Onload()
Const cWid = 220
Const cHei = 122
window.resizeTo cWid, cHei
window.MoveTo screen.width/1-(cWid/1),screen.height/1-((cHei/1) + 40 )

 document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData("TEXT"),"Fred@Email.com.au"

'<script language = "vbscript" type = "text/vbscript">

aOpt = Array("Fred email",_  
    "Bert email",_ 
    "Sally email",_
    "David email",_
    "Peter emal")

bOpt = Array("Fred@Email.com.au" , _                                                                       "Bert@Email.com.au" , _                                                                                                           
    "Sally@Email.com.au" , _                                                                                                             
    "David@Email.com.au" , _                                                                                                                 
    "Peter@Email.com.au")

sOpt = "<select id='entries' style='width:160px'>" 
     '    & "<option selected>" & document.title & "</option>"
For iOpt = 0 To UBound(aOpt)
    sOpt = sOpt & "<option>" & aOpt(iOpt) & "</option>"
Next           
   
sOpt = sOpt & "</select><p>" 
document.getElementById("opts").innerHTML = sOpt
End Sub

Sub Selected()

Dim iSel
    iSel = document.getElementById("entries").selectedIndex

  messij = "YOU SELECTED" & chr(13) & chr(13) & "          " & aopt(isel) & chr(13) & chr(13) & "WHICH CAUSED THE VALUE" _
         & chr(13) & chr(13) & "          " &  bopt(isel) & chr(13) & chr(13) & "TO BE COPIED TO THE CLIPBOARD"
 'msgbox messij
 document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData("TEXT"),bopt(isel)

End Sub

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id = "Resulta)" / style="text-align:center;" readonly style='width:160px'/ value= bOpt(isel)>
<body> 
<body bgColor="yellow">
<center>
<span id="resulta"></span>
<span id="opts"></span>
</center>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<input>` element formatting looks a bit weird why is there a bracket ) at the end of the `id` attribute (seems a strange name for an id) and there are forward slashes / in the middle of the element definition?

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't got errors appearing, I can't see how this `document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData("TEXT"),bopt(isel)` is correct syntax. Did you mean `document.parentwindow.clipboardData.SetData "TEXT", bopt(isel)`?

Answer (score 0):

I put this in a sub

```
document.getElementById("fixit").value = bopt(isel)
```

which accepted the variable value and I modified my original input which treated the variable name as text by removing value = parameter

```
<input type="text" id = "fixit" / style="text-align:center;" readonlyx style='width:160px'>
```

Input box now loading successfully with variable values

I found my solution in another Stackoverflow question but cannot locate it again in order to acknowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `Dim` to get the escape key to correctly quit:

```
Dim intKeyCode
```

I removed the explicit value being set for input box:

```
value= bOpt(isel)
```

I renamed the `Resulta)` text box to `Resulta` (which necessitated renaming the later span from `Resulta` to `Resultas` to avoid duplicate names).

Then, finally, I explicitly put the value into `Resulta` in the Sub Selected code:

```
resulta.value = bOpt(iSel)
```

I'd never seen an `onClick()` event added in the HTA section before.